# Where do knights train fastest in The Settlers?

Tags: the-settlers

I'm playing the original The Settlers game in DOS.  It seems like your knights train up from level 1 to level 5 relatively quickly at the main castle (as I said, *relatively*; the game is slow so it's still like an hour).  Do they train up at the same speed in storage depots, or is it a bit slower?  I see they also train up when they're stationed in large garrisons too, but I think that is definitely slower.

Answer (score 1):

They both train the same. The only ones that train slower are the guard towers and garrisons (since they are working, but it is also done automatically). The only item that looks to cause the speed to differ is their morale.

Morale seems to be determined by the number of gold bars that are in storage at the guard posts (or storage facilities). This will also go up/down if you take a hut with gold inside or lose a hut with gold inside.

[Source1](http://stanislavs.tripod.com/games/serfcity.faq) and [Source2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/565133-serf-city-life-is-feudal/faqs/2135)